# Fill Cell Down to Adjacent Columns last cell NOT from top row

Tags: vba, dynamic, formula, fill

I am trying to fill down a formula to the bottom cell of the adjacent column. Specifically Fill column A to the bottom row found in Column B. I can achieve this using the following code:

```
LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
```

The issue is that when the file is updated I will need the starting point (to fill down from) to be dynamic.  The first time the file is run the above code works because the file is empty.  The second time however column A may have data to row 100 and column B may have data to 200. So I cannot have the FillDown start at A2. It needs to start at the first empty cell in Column A (there are never empty cells in column A until the bottom of the data).

How can I make the starting point dynamic also?

This Code:

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
```

Selects the "starting point" I am looking for when there is already data in the columns but I can't seem to tie that in to my existing code.

Thanks !

Comment: Is there a problem with repeating the fill down for the entire column?  Unless you have a huge dataset you likely wouldn't notice the difference between that and just filling the empty cells.

Comment: @TimWilliams Column A is the date corresponding to when the work was done (once a month say).  So I need to keep the values that already exist in Column A but insert the new date for all the new lines being added to the worksheet.  I responded to your answer which worked but I need to keep the date (column A) the same in every row.  Can you suggest how to do this?  Basically a copy and paste between the last filled cell in Column A and the last row in column B that has data.

Comment: @TimWilliams The new edit works like a charm.  Very much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LastRowA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowB = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Fill down (will auto-increment)
Range("A" & LastRowA).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & LastRowA & ":A" & LastRowB)

'EDIT: fill with same fixed value...
Range("A" & (LastRowA+1) & ":A" & LastRowB).Value = Range("A" & LastRowA).Value
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This worked correctly.  However, Column A is a date and I now see that the AutoFill function makes the date grow by a day each row.  Is there a way to fill down but keep the value static? (More like a copy and paste)  the value I need to copy is always in the last row of Column A.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to fill down the formula:

`Range("A2:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown`